# Word or phrase for a person who sets their watch forward to prevent being late?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

My aunt does this. She sets her watch 15 mins early because she knows that she is chronically late all the time.

Is there a word or phrase specifically for the act of setting your watch forward with this intention? Or perhaps for the kind of person who tries to correct themselves with techniques like this?

Comment: There are the terms [*time optimist*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=time+optimist&spell=1) and *time realist*. Maybe your aunt is a realistic time optimist.

Comment: Time management awareness.

Comment: I'm curious. Does it actually help? Or does she mentally just subtract 15 mins when she reads the watch?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Maybe a little. My aunt is still late, but less so than she used to be.

Comment: @tchrist: Or self-delusional.

Comment: A retrocrastinator?

Comment: Wow, most people have semi-negative sounding words for this. I always thought of this as an optimistic, "seeking self improvement" kind of thing.

Comment: If your aunt is "chronically late all the time" then I suggest that her method isn't really that effective. :) A word that accurately describe her action and character might be: precautious. There is no designated expression to describe that specific action, I know many who used to put forward their watches a *few* minutes ahead, but not fifteen.

Comment: I just pulled a number our if the air. I don't remember for sure if it was 15 or not and she did get better later in her life.

Comment: I thought of one, your aunt is **watchful**!

Comment: I love the play on words

Comment: Alternatively, her time-saving tactic could be be described as being *prudent*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's extremely foolish and imprudent. Say it's 10:00, but your clock reads 10:15. Your boss calls you up and tells you "there's an important meeting in 30 minutes". You look at the clock and deduce that you should be there at 10:45. But your boss is expecting you to be there at 10:30. Oops.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, but she *knows* her **watch** is 15 minutes fast, and nowadays we are constantly reminded what the time is by our computers, cell phones etc. If it works for her, then who are we to criticise? If there is an important meeting she should already be at work, and in all work places there are clocks on the walls.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's the clocks on the walls that cause this to fail. And if she knows her watch is 15 minutes fast and knows she has to adjust for this to be on time rather than late or early, then what's the point?

Comment: I fully agree, it's a self-defeating task. But she's not the first and she won't be the last.

Comment: I do this too, with my alarm clock. It wakes me up about 15 minutes earlier than I need to be up every day, and it actually works. When I'm just awoken and still groggy, I forget that I have 15 extra minutes, and I use those 15 minutes to wake up, rather than dozing for an extra 15 minutes and _then_ spend 15 minutes waking up.

Answer (score 2):

There is, as far as I am aware, no expression which describes the act of putting forward a watch several minutes in order to prevent [tardiness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tardiness) or chronic lateness. With the advent of cell/mobile/smart phones, laptops etc.,  wristwatches will becoming obsolete (in my opinion) and any need for coining such a phrase or word is doomed.

Instead the OP could use several timely expressions to describe his aunt's strategy. The first that sprang to mind was *[precautious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Precautious)*. But that's a bit tedious and uninspiring, so bearing in mind that time is of essence, may I suggest the following expressions and idiom (with tongue stuck firmly in cheek).

- Anticipator, *n.*
- Ahead of time,  *idiom.*
  *My aunt is always ahead of time*
- Anachronistic, *adj.*
  *when something (or someone) is chronologically misplaced*
- Chronologist, *n.*
- Horologist, *n.*
  *an expert in horology*
- Timesaver, *adj.*, *n.*
- Watchful, *adj.*
- Watchwoman, *n.* (from the established noun *watchman*)

Answer (score -1):

absent-minded, daylight savings dawdler